# QVTKOpenGLWidget with Qt 5.9.5

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

I am trying to integrate a VTK render window in a Qt GUI. Using QtCreator/Designer, I added an openGLWidget to the MainWindow and promoted it to QVTKOpenGLWidget.  When I try to compile, the compiler does not find the header "QVTKOpenGLWidget.h".  After I manually added this header to the project, the linker apparently does not find the right library and gives the error:

/home/christian/InSync/Tmp/build-Viewer3D-Desktop_f4eeec-Debug/ui_mainwindow.h:42: error: undefined reference to `QVTKOpenGLWidget::QVTKOpenGLWidget(QWidget*, QFlags)'

I added first the vtk libraries that appeared most likely to contain QVTKOpenGLWidget, later ALL vtk libraries, but the problem persists.
I would greatly appreciate ideas on how to make this minimal example work.

I am using Qt 5.9.5 and VTK 7.1

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Instead of copying stuff from libraries around, rather use the `-I` and `-L` compiler / linker flags to provide the directories where the header and library files should be looked up.

Comment: _"... how to make this minimal example ..."_ What you posted is far from what's considered as a [MCVE], sorry.

Comment: There are multiples minimal usage example in VTK. See `GUISupport/Qt/Testing/Cxx/QVTKWidget*`